# Sorted dataview to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataview

I have the following method:

```
private DataTable getsortedtable(DataTable dt)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Name desc";
    //I would need to return the datatable sorted.
}
```

My issue is that I cannot change the return type of this method and I have to return a DataTable but i would like return it sorted.

Are there any magic hidden property of `dt.DefaultView` to return the dt sorted?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
 private DataTable getSortedTable(DataTable dt)
 {
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = "columnName DESC";
    return dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

do this

```
private DataTable getsortedtable(DataTable dt)
{
    //do the operation for sort   
    return dataView.ToTable();
}
```