# DataTable Sorting Lost When Done Via Method

Tags: c#, sorting, methods, datatable

I created 2 lines of code to sort my DataTable. I needed to do this several times, so I then moved the 2 lines into a simple method that I would call each time I needed to sort.

However, when I call the method in order to sort my DataTable, the DataTable does not maintain the sorting.  There must be something taking place here that I am not aware of and that I do not understand.

My 2 lines that work as I want them to:

```
private void loadData()
{
  DataTable scheduleData = new DataTable();

  /*
  code that fills the DataTable with data and creates the groupOrderBy string
  */

  scheduleData.DefaultView.Sort = "SortDate, Finish";
  scheduleData = scheduleData.DefaultView.ToTable();

  scheduleData.Columns.RemoveAt(0);  // at this point, when I view the
                                     // DataTable scheduleData, the rows are sorted correctly
}
```

When I view the `scheduleData` DataTable after the above lines run, it looks like how I want it (the rows are in the correct order).

So, I tried to move them into a method as shown below:

```
private void loadData()
{
  DataTable scheduleData = new DataTable();

  /*
  code that fills the DataTable with data and creates the groupOrderBy string
  */

  sortDT(scheduleData, "SortDate, Finish")

  scheduleData.Columns.RemoveAt(0);  // at this point, when I view the
                                     // DataTable scheduleData, the rows are no longer sorted
                                     // (they are back to their original positions)
}

private void sortDT(DataTable dt, string sortString)
{
  dt.DefaultView.Sort = sortString;
  dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();  // at this point, when I view the
                                  // DataTable dt, the rows are sorted correctly
}
```

During the method's execution, viewing the "dt" DataTable shows correctly sorted rows.  After the method's execution, viewing the `scheduleData` DataTable shows rows that are not sorted.

**What am I not understanding here?**

I thought that maybe it had to do with the DataTable in the method ("dt") versus the `scheduleData` one. Perhaps I was sorting "dt", but it wasn't actually affecting the `scheduleData` table that I passed into the method (so I should be using a method that doesn't return void?).

So, I tried this instead of the `scheduleData.Columns.RemoveAt(0);` line above:

```
private void loadData()
{
  DataTable scheduleData = new DataTable();

  /*
  code that fills the DataTable with data and creates the groupOrderBy string
  */

  deleteColumn(scheduleData);
}

private void deleteColumn(DataTable dt)
{
  dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

That simple method works, and when the code execution resumes after calling it, the `scheduleData` DataTable has had its Column[0] removed.

Obviously, I'm rather new to C#/programming, so I may just be missing something very simple. I don't understand why one method that manipulates my DataTable works (the removing of a column), but another method that manipulates the DataTable does not work (the sorting).

Comment: Returning void is ok because DataTable is referencetype and the changes should reflect. But i'm not that sure if .ToTable() works. Because this creates a new DataTable object. And this will be not reflected. Try to use Property .Table please. It's even better for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `sortDT` method, you are reassiging the `dt` variable to the result of `dt.DefaultView.ToTable()`, thus the reference to `dt` changes within the method. The change of the reference doesn't get reflected outside the method. So, you basically have two options:

1. Return the result of `dt.DefaultView.ToTable()` from your `sortDT`. (In that case I would call the method `GetSortedDataTable`.
2. Pass `dt` as reference to the method, as stated [here in the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx).

I'd prefer the first option.

Comment: Would DefaultView.Table work? There is no new Table created. Or does this ignore the sorting? I'm not sure but i think this would be faster then create a new table.

Comment: Hm, not quite sure, but I think `ToTable()` is required. This is also used in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3987217/1384848).

Comment: Ok just got some performance issues with accessing ToTable massive in a grid event. There i could change to .Table which is quite faster on heavy access. But you will be right, this will ignore the sorting i guess.

Comment: @M.E. Thanks for this answer and the link to the MSDN documentation.  I think that I understand why my code behaved differently that I expected.  You mention that you would prefer the first option- any particular reason?

Comment: In that case this is just a matter of personal preference. In my opinion, methods with return values are easier to handle than using `ref` parameters (e.g. you can do method chaining when using return values instead of returning `void`, like `GetSortedDataTable("...").DoSomethingElse()` )

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing a reference variable, but resetting the reference in the method.  The quickest way to resolve this issue is to use the ref keyword.

```
private void loadData()
{
    DataTable scheduleData = new DataTable();
    sortDT(ref scheduleData, "SortDate, Finish")
    scheduleData.Columns.RemoveAt(0); 
}

private void sortDT(ref DataTable dt, string sortString)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = sortString;
    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();  
}
```

You could also have SortDt return the DataTable.

```
private void loadData()
{
    DataTable scheduleData = sortDT(scheduleData, "SortDate, Finish");
    scheduleData.Columns.RemoveAt(0);  
}

private DataTable sortDT(DataTable dt, string sortString)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = sortString;
    return dt.DefaultView.ToTable();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options either use ref or return DataTable.

```
private void sortDT(ref DataTable dt, string sortString)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = sortString;
    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();  // at this point, when I view the
                              // DataTable dt, the rows are sorted correctly
}


private DataTable sortDT(DataTable dt, string sortString)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = sortString;
    return dt.DefaultView.ToTable();  
}
```